# Flip connectivity of tilings by $2 \times 1$ and $1 \times 2$ rectangles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Suppose that a region is simply connected and can be tiled by $2 \times 1$ and $1 \times 2$ rectangles. A flip is the local move replacing two $1 \times 2$ rectangles sharing a long side with two $2 \times 1$ rectangles sharing a long side (and vice verse). Are any two tilings connected by a sequence of such local moves?